# ComboBox changing selection index doesn't work when ItemSource is updated from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two `ComboBox` which I update the content of second `ComboBox` when the first one is changed. Everything works okay except that the updated `ComboBox` would always show an empty entry when it is updated.

Here is a screenshot from it:

[image]

Here is how I update it:

```
var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    comboDetail.ItemsSource = new List<string> {  model.Detail[0] ,  model.Detail[1] };

else if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    comboDetail.ItemsSource = new List<string> { model.Detail[2] };

else if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    comboDetail.ItemsSource = new List<string> { model.Detail[3] , model.Detail[4] };

comboDetail.SelectedItem = 0;
comboDetail.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: @PratikGhag That part is not the issue here. I can successfully update the second `ComboBox`. The problem is when I update the second one, it wouldn't select the first entry as I expect when I use `comboDetail.SelectedItem = 0;`. So only at first selection there is an empty string which goes away when I select one of the other strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want select the First element. but SelecteItem Determines which item-object is selected and not by position.

instead

```
comboDetail.SelectedItem = 0;
comboDetail.Items.Refresh();
```

write:

```
comboDetail.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed it after looking at it for one hour!